# FAKE CscHelper: Csc vs csc?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I don't understand the difference between these two.

I want to compile a single c# file into a dll using FAKE's CscHelper. This is my build file:

```
// include Fake lib
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open CscHelper

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    ["Discover.cs"] |> csc (fun p -> { p with Output="Discover.dll"; Target=Library })
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

This is the error I get:

```
build.fsx(7,24): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    string list -> unit
but given a
    string list -> int
The type 'unit' does not match the type 'int'
```

If I replace "csc" with "Csc" it compiles correctly. Why? In the documentation the code samples are literally identical other than that single character. The method signatures appear the same other than return type. Why are there two variants and how do you make the lowercase one work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower case form is proper. You can always pipe the results to the ignore function to be sure to return a unit ().

```
// include Fake lib
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open CscHelper

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    ["Discover.cs"] |> csc (fun p -> { p with Output="Discover.dll"; Target=Library }) |> ignore
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

The actual tool tip tells you what is going on (it returns *exit status code* which is of type int):

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       'string list -> unit'
>   but given a
>       'string list -> int'
>   The type 'unit' does not match the type 'int'
>   val csc : setParams:(CscParams -> CscParams) -> inputFiles:string list -> int
>   Full name: Fake.CscHelper.csc
>   Compiles the given C# source files with the specified parameters.
>
> ### Parameters
>
> - `setParams` - Function used to overwrite the default CSC parameters.
> - `inputFiles` - The C# input files.
>
> ### Returns
>
> The *exit status code* of the compile process.
>
> ### Sample
>
> ["file1.cs"; "file2.cs"] |> csc (fun parameters -> { parameters with Output = ... Target = ... ... })

You may have already found this out or not, but it is good that everyone knows  there are options. Thank you. Good day.